# function syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, brackets

Why this anonymous function

```
(function () {
  return ("i am a function")
})()
```

is equivalent to

```
function hi () {
  return ("i am a function")
}
```

the function work with `hi()`

Also why if I removed the brackets for the anonymous function it does not work

```
function () {
  return ("i am a function")
}()
```

Comment: Check my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-the-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/

Comment: You need to read about `IIFE` https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-stop-feeling-iffy-about-using-an-iife-7b0292aba174

Comment: If you don't use the parentheses, the function is evaluated as a Function Statement, and function statements cannot be anonymous, the name is required by the grammar.

Comment: your first one is Immediately invoked function ... so when you declare a function as your hi function after you have to call with hi() ... but  your last exaple doesn't work becouse you return a value but you never "call"  that  so if you change the last as: `myMessage=function () {
  return ("i am a function")
}()`