# What does this syntax mean " function(a,d){...}(Jquery,...); "

Tags: javascript, iife

I know, similar questions have been asked but none answered my question of What does the second `()` mean?
And also no the syntax is not `(function...)` rather its just  `function(a,d){...}(Jquery,...);`

Is it that we are making objects of Jquery, I am also using Hammer.js so basically the second paranthesis has (Jquery, Hammer)

Comment: It is an [immediately invoked function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-the-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax)

Comment: @Quentin, I think you tagged the wrong dupe.