# asynchronous .js file loading syntax

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I noticed that there seems to be a couple of slightly different syntaxes for loading js files asynchronously, and I was wondering if there's any difference between the two, or if they both pretty much function the same. I'm guessing they work the same, but just wanted to make sure one method isn't better than the other for some reason. :)

**Method One**

```
(function() {
    var d=document,
    h=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    s=d.createElement('script');
    s.type='text/javascript';
    s.src='/js/myfile.js';
    h.appendChild(s);
})(); /* note ending parenthesis and curly brace */
```

**Method Two (Saw this in Facebook's code)**

```
(function() {
    var d=document,
    h=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    s=d.createElement('script');
    s.type='text/javascript';
    s.async=true;
    s.src='/js/myfile.js';
    h.appendChild(s);
}()); /* note ending parenthesis and curly brace */
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only difference that I notice is the `s.async=true;` in the Facebook method.

> The `async` and `defer` attributes are boolean attributes that indicate how the script should be executed.
>
> There are three possible modes that can be selected using these attributes. **If the `async` attribute is present, then the script will be executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available.** If the `async` attribute is not present but the defer attribute is present, then the script is executed when the page has finished parsing. If neither attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.

Source and Further reading: [Whatwg.org HTML 5: The script element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async)

As for the advantages, you may want to check what Google had to say on this last December:

- [Google Analytics Launches Asynchronous Tracking](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/12/google-analytics-launches-asynchronous.html)

Comment: Cool, thanks. Isn't s.asynch=true pointless in this case though, since the script is injected into the head tag? And as far as the syntax on the parenthesis: (function(){ ... })(); vs: (function(){ ... }()); - are those pretty much the same?

Comment: @taber: Yes the parenthesis syntax achieves the same goal. ie: the function is evaluated as a function expression instead of a function statement. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-objectfunctionclass-declaration/442408#442408 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/1634321#1634321 (especially the last comment).

Comment: @taber: I don't think that the fact that it is inserted in the `<head>` makes any difference. (But I have no references or tests to back this).

Comment: The async attribute is an HTML5 feature. And the parenthesis doesn't matter. They are the same. jslint prefers `function(){}())`

Comment: Thanks for adding the GA link. Yeah, it looks like "async" is just a future-proofing of the script to "officially" tell browsers (Firefox 3.6 for now) to load the script asynchronously. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this and created a library for this that includes support for firing a callback when the script eventually loads.

```
Sigma.async_script_load('http://example.com/underscore-min.js', '_', function() {
  _([1,2,3,2,3,1]).uniq();
});
```

https://github.com/ssoroka/sigma