# How to load multiple javascript asynchronously?

Tags: javascript

i have around 5 to 6 JavaScript which i put it at the bottom of page
however I wanted to load all this JavaScript in one function so all of them download on the page
Asynchronously. Can anyone suggest how can i do that? Some syntaxes will definitely helpful

`

Comment: Why don't you post your efforts so far and we'll point you in the right direction from there

Comment: We need more information than this.  Do you want asynchronous code, or do you want the code to load asynchronously?  Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631845/asynchronous-javascript-loading-executing

Answer (score 5):

On newer browsers you can use the async attribute:

```
<scritp src="yourscript.js" type="text/javascript" async=true ></script>
```

Or for wider support you can append the script to an already processed tag in the document:

Edit:

```
function loadScript (scriptpath){
    var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var ss=document.createElement('script');
    ss.type='text/javascript';
    ss.async=true;
    ss.src= scriptpath;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ss,s);
}
```

And you can load them like so:

```
loadScript('script1.js');
loadScript('script2.js');
loadScript('script3.js');
loadScript('script4.js');
```

Comment: While useful, I don't think that this is what the OP is asking.  That said, I forgot about the async attribute so I found it interesting :)

Comment: You are right, there is a second option

Comment: the above is only for one script how about another 4 external js file??

Comment: loadScript('script1.js');
loadScript('script2.js'); like that in above javascript function? sorry i am bit confuse here?? if you can give me syntax would be great help...sorry i don't know much JS

Comment: You can call them anyway you want

Comment: tell me if this is the right method <script type="text/javascript">
function loadScript (scriptpath){
    var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var ssa=document.createElement('script');
    ss.type='text/javascript';
    ss.async=true;
    ss.src= scriptpath;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ss,s);
}

loadScript('compressed1.js');
loadScript('compressed2.js');



</script>
it gives me error  "ss is not defined "

Comment: You have a typo on your code. you have `ssa` instead of `ss`, other than that everything is fine, see my updated code