# JavaScript From Remote Site Causes Issues on Our Site When The Remote Site Goes Down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Greeting all
In our site, we include javascript from a remote site that is used to pop-up an emergency banner/window when someone from the remote site initiates it.  If there is a school wide emergency this is one means of alerting everyone.  The remote site is not ours and we only include a call to their js:

```
<script src="https://embanner.univcomm.cornell.edu/OWC-emergency-banner.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Problem:
When the remote site goes down, for whatever reason, some pages in our site that use our home-grown javascript/jquery have javascript related problems.  I'm just wondering if anyone might have an idea on why this is? When the remote site is working, we have no problems.  When their site goes down, some of our sites using our js have issues.

When their site is down, we obviously cannot pull in their javascript file, but why would that adversely affect our code?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It is loaded in a manner that creates whats known as a "blocking operation." Consider loading it asynchronously to avoid this.

Non-Blocking Operations as described here :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm

Comment: Can you tell me how to load it asynchronously?  I'm not sure I'm at the level to understand that article.  sorry.

Comment: This post on StackOverflow explained things for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631845/asynchronous-javascript-loading-executing