# load scripts asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, asynchronous

I am using several plugins, custom widgets and some other libraries from JQuery. as a result I have several .js and .css files. I need to create a loader for my site because it takes some time to load. it will be nice if I can display the loader before importing all the:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myFunctions.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
... 
....
 etc
```

I have found several tutorials that enable me to import a JavaScript library asynchronously. for example I can do something like:

```
  (function () {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js';
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
```

for some reason when I do the same thing for all my files the pages does not work. I have been trying for so long to try to find where the problem is but I just cannot find it. First I thought that it was probably because some javascript functions depended on the others. but I loaded them in the right order using the time out function when one completed I proceeded with the next and the page still behaves weird. for example I am not able to click on links etc... animations still work though..

### Anyways

Here is what I have been thinking... I believe browsers have a cache that's why it takes a long time to load the page for the first time and the next time it is quick. so what I am thinking of doing is replacing my index.html page with a page that loads all this files asynchronously. when ajax is done loading all those files redirect to the page that I plan on using. when using that page it should not take long to load since the files should alredy be included on the cache of the browser. on my index page (page where .js and .css file get loaded asynchronously) I don't care of getting errors. I will just be displaying a loader and redirecting the page when done...

Is this idea a good alternative? or should I keep trying on implementing the asynchronously methods?

---

### EDIT

the way I load everything async is like:

```
importScripts();

function importScripts()
{
    //import: jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
    getContent("js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js",function (code) {
                var s = document.createElement('script');
                s.type = 'text/javascript';
                //s.async = true;
                s.innerHTML=code;
                var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
                setTimeout(insertNext1,1);
            });


    //import: jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
    function insertNext1()
    {
        getContent("js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js",function (code) {
                    var s = document.createElement('script');
                    s.type = 'text/javascript';
                    s.innerHTML=code;
                    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
                    setTimeout(insertNext2,1);
                });
    }

    //import: jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
    function insertNext2()
    {

        getContent("css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css",function (code) {
                    var s = document.createElement('link');
                    s.type = 'text/css';
                    s.rel ="stylesheet";
                    s.innerHTML=code;
                    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
                    setTimeout(insertNext3,1);
                });
    }

    //import: main.css
    function insertNext3()
    {

        getContent("css/main.css",function (code) {
                    var s = document.createElement('link');
                    s.type = 'text/css';
                    s.rel ="stylesheet";
                    s.innerHTML=code;
                    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
                    setTimeout(insertNext4,1);
                });
    }

    //import: jquery.imgpreload.min.js
    function insertNext4()
    {
        getContent("js/farinspace/jquery.imgpreload.min.js",function (code) {
                    var s = document.createElement('script');
                    s.type = 'text/javascript';
                    s.innerHTML=code;
                    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
                    setTimeout(insertNext5,1);
                });
    }


    //import: marquee.js
    function insertNext5()
    {
        getContent("js/marquee.js",function (code) {
                    var s = document.createElement('script');
                    s.type = 'text/javascript';
                    s.innerHTML=code;
                    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
                    setTimeout(insertNext6,1);
                });
    }


    //import: marquee.css
    function insertNext6()
    {

        getContent("css/marquee.css",function (code) {
                    var s = document.createElement('link');
                    s.type = 'text/css';
                    s.rel ="stylesheet";
                    s.innerHTML=code;
                    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
                    setTimeout(insertNext,1);
                });
    }



    function insertNext()
    {
        setTimeout(pageReadyMan,10);        
    }
}


// get the content of url and pass that content to specified function
function getContent( url, callBackFunction )
{
     // attempt to create the XMLHttpRequest and make the request
     try
     {
        var asyncRequest; // variable to hold XMLHttpRequest object
        asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); // create request object

        // register event handler
        asyncRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            stateChange(asyncRequest, callBackFunction);
        } 
        asyncRequest.open( 'GET', url, true ); // prepare the request
        asyncRequest.send( null ); // send the request
     } // end try
     catch ( exception )
     {
        alert( 'Request failed.' );
     } // end catch
} // end function getContent

// call function whith content when ready
function stateChange(asyncRequest, callBackFunction)
{
     if ( asyncRequest.readyState == 4 && asyncRequest.status == 200 )
     {
           callBackFunction(asyncRequest.responseText);
     } // end if
} // end function stateChange
```

and the weird part is that all the style's work plus all the javascript functions. the page is frozen for some reason though...

Comment: [MDN has a very good, modern, well-maintained guide to dynamically importing scripts.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#dynamically_importing_scripts)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

A couple solutions for async loading:

```
//this function will work cross-browser for loading scripts asynchronously
function loadScript(src, callback)
{
  var s,
      r,
      t;
  r = false;
  s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.src = src;
  s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //console.log( this.readyState ); //uncomment this line to see which ready states are called.
    if ( !r && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'complete') )
    {
      r = true;
      callback();
    }
  };
  t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
}
```

If you've already got jQuery on the page, just use:

[`$.getScript(url, successCallback)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)*

Additionally, it's possible that your scripts are being loaded/executed before the document is done loading, meaning that you'd need to wait for `document.ready` before events can be bound to the elements.

It's not possible to tell specifically what your issue is without seeing the code.

The simplest solution is to keep all of your scripts inline at the bottom of the page, that way they don't block the loading of HTML content while they execute. It also avoids the issue of having to asynchronously load each required script.

If you have a particularly fancy interaction that isn't always used that requires a larger script of some sort, it could be useful to avoid loading that particular script until it's needed (lazy loading).

<sub>* [scripts loaded with `$.getScript` will likely not be cached](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#caching-requests)</sub>

---

For anyone who can use modern features such as the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object, the `loadScript` function has become significantly simpler:

```
function loadScript(src) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var s;
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = src;
        s.onload = resolve;
        s.onerror = reject;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    });
}
```

Be aware that this version no longer accepts a `callback` argument as the returned promise will handle callback. What previously would have been `loadScript(src, callback)` would now be `loadScript(src).then(callback)`.

This has the added bonus of being able to detect and handle failures, for example one could call...

```
loadScript(cdnSource)
    .catch(loadScript.bind(null, localSource))
    .then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

...and it would handle CDN outages gracefully.

Comment: I am about to start trying that out. but if I load those scripts on a different page when I redirect the page to a different page and that page happens to have the same scripts they should not take time to load. they should be in the cache right? so should't I implement that technique instead?

Comment: Sync and async loading both take advantage of the browser cache.

Comment: I changed and appended the child to the head tag instead of the body...           ..var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);

Comment: @TonoNam, you could just use `document.head.appendChild`, however there are some niche issues with adding scripts to the `<head>`; nothing that would prevent scripts from loading and executing.

Comment: but that means that large minifed js for example, will load on every page refresh and won't be cached as compare to if they were in the head section, am I right?

Comment: @IdanShechter, caching is completely independent of the location of where the script is inserted. The browser will cache any requests (such as the `src` of a `<script>`) respecting the cache headers sent by the server. Caching is complicated, so I highly recommend that if you have questions regarding how it works, that you [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @zzzzBov `document.head` is not supported in IE8-. Why bother with `readyState` if you don’t plan to support IE anyway? :)

Comment: @David, I hadn't realized `document.head` was that recent of an addition. I've updated the script to work in cases where it's called before `body` exists as well.

Comment: I had to use t.parentNode.insertBefore (as opposed to t.parent).

Comment: does adding script tag with js, causes it to load asynchronously.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, if you're writing an additional script tag with `document.write` before the document has loaded, the script will be  executed synchronously as part of loading the page, and will not include any asynchronous callback behavior on its own. If you're creating a script element and adding it to the page, then you'll have access to add event listeners to trigger asynchronously. **tl;dr:** it depends on how you're loading the script with JS.

Comment: Probably, it would be better to check type of callback (if (typeof callback === 'function')) before invoking.

Comment: @AlexVauch, you can feel free to modify this script however you so choose, however anyone calling the script as written should be aware that the first parameter is required and must be a string, and the second parameter is required and must be a function. I don't see any good reason to enforce this contract in code. It *might* be useful to make `callback` optional, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I tried various methods for loading a local "file:///" script and this the only method that worked in the new MsEdge (Chromium), including the various jQuery .getScript, .getJson, etc. The rest are all blocked due to CORS.

Answer (score 38):

HTML5's new 'async' attribute is supposed to do the trick. 'defer' is also supported in most browsers if you care about IE.

async - The HTML

```
<script async src="siteScript.js" onload="myInit()"></script>
```

defer - The HTML

```
<script defer src="siteScript.js" onload="myInit()"></script>
```

While analyzing the new adsense ad unit code I noticed the attribute and a search lead me here: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async

Comment: from my understanding after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774373/asynchronous-js-file-loading-syntax, asyn is not for loading, but for determining when to run the javascript contained.

Comment: The defer attribute causes the browser to defer execution of the script until after the document has been loaded and parsed and is ready to be manipulated. The async attribute causes the browser to run the script as soon as possible but not to block document parsing while the script is being downloaded

Comment: "asyn is not for loading, but for determining when to run the javascript contained"  This is not contradictory; In all cases, the browser will start loading the script ASAP. But *without* `async` or `defer` it will block the rendering while it loads. Setting `async` will tell it to not block and run the script ASAP. Setting `defer` will tell it to not block but wait with *running* the script until the page is done. Usually it's no problem to run scripts ASAP as long as they don't have any dependencies (e.g. jQuery). If one script has dependencies on another, use `onLoad` to wait for it.

Comment: @StijndeWitt
What if Neither async nor defer specified?

Comment: @MohammedShareefC If you specify neither, you get something closely resembling sync behaviour; the browser blocks further processing while it downloads and runs the script. So effectively the default behavior is sync. But because this is detrimental for performance, browsers will work around it as much as they can. They can go ahead with parsing, loading and applying CSS etc... They cannot however start running the next script fragment. So stuff will block. By setting async, you are telling the browser that it's ok to go ahead and you will make sure that you make it work yourself.

Answer (score 9):

I loaded the scripts asynchronously (html 5 has that feature) when all the scripts where done loading I redirected the page to index2.html where index2.html uses the same libraries. Because browsers have a cache once the page redirects to index2.html, index2.html loads in less than a second because it has all it needs to load the page.  In my index.html page I also load the images that I plan on using so that the browser place those images on the cache. so my index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Project Management</title>

    <!-- the purpose of this page is to load all the scripts on the browsers cache so that pages can load fast from now on -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function stylesheet(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('link');
            s.type = 'text/css';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = url;
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
        }

        function script(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = url;
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
        }

        //load scritps to the catche of browser
        (function () {            
                stylesheet('css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css');
                stylesheet('css/main.css');
                stylesheet('css/marquee.css');
                stylesheet('css/mainTable.css');

                script('js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js');
                script('js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js');
                script('js/myFunctions.js');
                script('js/farinspace/jquery.imgpreload.min.js');
                script('js/marquee.js');            
        })();

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       // once the page is loaded go to index2.html
        window.onload = function () {
            document.location = "index2.html";
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="cover" style="position:fixed; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:Black; z-index:100;">Loading</div>

<img src="images/home/background.png" />
<img src="images/home/3.png"/>
<img src="images/home/6.jpg"/>
<img src="images/home/4.png"/>
<img src="images/home/5.png"/>
<img src="images/home/8.jpg"/>
<img src="images/home/9.jpg"/>
<img src="images/logo.png"/>
<img src="images/logo.png"/>
<img src="images/theme/contentBorder.png"/>

</body>
</html>
```

another nice thing about this is that I may place a loader in the page and when the page is done loading the loader will go away and in a matte of milliseconds the new page will be running.

Comment: @MohammedShareefC It's irony. A special page just to preload stuff doesn't sound like a good idea SEO wise. Preloading is great, but you don't need to redirect to achieve it. Just stick the links in a hidden div and the browser will take care of it for you automatically. Then don't redirect but just render the actual page. **COPY-PASTERS READ THIS**: Please change the ISO-88591 encoding to UTF-8 before using any of this HTML so the rest of us can get out of encoding hell anytime soon. Thanks!

Comment: Please look at my new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously/45490192#45490192

Answer (score 8):

Several notes:

- `s.async = true` is not very correct for HTML5 doctype, correct is `s.async = 'async'` (actually using `true` **is correct**, thanks to [amn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254343/amn) who pointed it out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously/14813913#comment63569037_14813913) just below)
- Using timeouts to control the order is not very good and safe, and you also make the loading time much larger, to equal the sum of all timeouts!

Since there is a recent reason to load files asynchronously, but in order, I'd recommend a bit more functional-driven way over your example (remove `console.log` for production use :) ):

```
(function() {
    var prot = ("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https://":"http://");

    var scripts = [
        "path/to/first.js",
        "path/to/second.js",
        "path/to/third.js"
    ];

    function completed() { console.log('completed'); }  // FIXME: remove logs

    function checkStateAndCall(path, callback) {
        var _success = false;
        return function() {
            if (!_success && (!this.readyState || (this.readyState == 'complete'))) {
                _success = true;
                console.log(path, 'is ready'); // FIXME: remove logs
                callback();
            }
        };
    }

    function asyncLoadScripts(files) {
        function loadNext() { // chain element
            if (!files.length) completed();
            var path = files.shift();
            var scriptElm = document.createElement('script');
            scriptElm.type = 'text/javascript';
            scriptElm.async = true;
            scriptElm.src = prot+path;
            scriptElm.onload = scriptElm.onreadystatechange = \
                checkStateAndCall(path, loadNext); // load next file in chain when
                                                   // this one will be ready 
            var headElm = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            headElm.appendChild(scriptElm);
        }
        loadNext(); // start a chain
    }

    asyncLoadScripts(scripts);
})();
```

Comment: `s.async = true` is *correct*. The property `async` is specified explicitly as a boolean in W3C's HTML 5 recommendation at https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async. You are confusing the `async` *attribute* with the `async` property exposed by objects implementing the `HTMLScriptElement` DOM interface. Indeed, when manipulating the corresponding attribute of the element through something like `Element.setAttribute`, you should use `element.setAttribute("async", "async")` as all HTML attributes are first and foremost text.

Comment: "Since there is a recent reason to load files asynchronously, but in order, I'd recommend a bit more functional-driven way over your example [...]". I know async is usually "better", but what "recent" reason are you refering to?

Comment: I changed 'if (!files.length) completed();' adding a 'return': 'if (!files.length) {completed(); return;}'

Answer (score 8):

Example from google

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js?onload=onLoadCallback';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to HTML5, you can now declare the scripts that you want to load asynchronously by adding "async" in the  tag:

```
<script async>...</script>
```

Note: The async attribute is only for external scripts (and should only be used if the src attribute is present).

Note: There are several ways an external script can be executed:

- If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing)
- If async is not present and defer is present: The script is executed when the page has finished parsing
- If neither async or defer is present: The script is fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues parsing the page

See this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little post to help out with this, you can read more here https://timber.io/snippets/asynchronously-load-a-script-in-the-browser-with-javascript/, but I've attached the helper class below. It will automatically wait for a script to load and return a specified window attribute once it does.

```
export default class ScriptLoader {
  constructor (options) {
    const { src, global, protocol = document.location.protocol } = options
    this.src = src
    this.global = global
    this.protocol = protocol
    this.isLoaded = false
  }

  loadScript () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Create script element and set attributes
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      script.type = 'text/javascript'
      script.async = true
      script.src = `${this.protocol}//${this.src}`

      // Append the script to the DOM
      const el = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
      el.parentNode.insertBefore(script, el)

      // Resolve the promise once the script is loaded
      script.addEventListener('load', () => {
        this.isLoaded = true
        resolve(script)
      })

      // Catch any errors while loading the script
      script.addEventListener('error', () => {
        reject(new Error(`${this.src} failed to load.`))
      })
    })
  }

  load () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.isLoaded) {
        try {
          await this.loadScript()
          resolve(window[this.global])
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e)
        }
      } else {
        resolve(window[this.global])
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Usage is like this:

```
const loader = new Loader({
    src: 'cdn.segment.com/analytics.js',
    global: 'Segment',
})

// scriptToLoad will now be a reference to `window.Segment`
const scriptToLoad = await loader.load()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would complete zzzzBov's answer with a check for the presence of callback and allow passing of arguments:

```
    function loadScript(src, callback, args) {
      var s, r, t;
      r = false;
      s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.src = src;
      if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
        s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (!r && (!this.readyState || this.readyState === 'complete')) {
            r = true;
            callback.apply(args);
          }
        };
      };
      t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      t.parent.insertBefore(s, t);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great contemporary solution to the asynchronous script loading though it only address the js script with **async false**.

There is a great article written in  **www.html5rocks.com** - [Deep dive into the murky waters of script loading](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/#toc-aggressive-optimisation) .

After considering many possible solutions, the author concluded that adding js scripts to the end of body element is the best possible way to avoid blocking page rendering by js scripts.

In the mean time, the author added another good alternate solution for those people who are desperate to load and execute scripts asynchronously.

Considering you've four scripts named `script1.js, script2.js, script3.js, script4.js` then you can do it with **applying async = false**:

```
[
  'script1.js',
  'script2.js',
  'script3.js',
  'script4.js'
].forEach(function(src) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.async = false;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

Now, **Spec says**: Download together, execute in order as soon as all download.

**Firefox < 3.6, Opera says:** I have no idea what this “async” thing is, but it just so happens I execute scripts added via JS in the order they’re added.

**Safari 5.0 says:** I understand “async”, but don’t understand setting it to “false” with JS. I’ll execute your scripts as soon as they land, in whatever order.

**IE < 10 says:** No idea about “async”, but there is a workaround using “onreadystatechange”.

**Everything else says:** I’m your friend, we’re going to do this by the book.

**Now, the full code with IE < 10 workaround:**

```
var scripts = [
  'script1.js',
  'script2.js',
  'script3.js',
  'script4.js'
];
var src;
var script;
var pendingScripts = [];
var firstScript = document.scripts[0];

// Watch scripts load in IE
function stateChange() {
  // Execute as many scripts in order as we can
  var pendingScript;
  while (pendingScripts[0] && ( pendingScripts[0].readyState == 'loaded' || pendingScripts[0].readyState == 'complete' ) ) {
    pendingScript = pendingScripts.shift();
    // avoid future loading events from this script (eg, if src changes)
    pendingScript.onreadystatechange = null;
    // can't just appendChild, old IE bug if element isn't closed
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(pendingScript, firstScript);
  }
}

// loop through our script urls
while (src = scripts.shift()) {
  if ('async' in firstScript) { // modern browsers
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = false;
    script.src = src;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
  else if (firstScript.readyState) { // IE<10
    // create a script and add it to our todo pile
    script = document.createElement('script');
    pendingScripts.push(script);
    // listen for state changes
    script.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
    // must set src AFTER adding onreadystatechange listener
    // else we’ll miss the loaded event for cached scripts
    script.src = src;
  }
  else { // fall back to defer
    document.write('<script src="' + src + '" defer></'+'script>');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for HTML5, you can use the 'prefetch'

`<link rel="prefetch" href="/style.css" as="style" />`

have a look at 'preload' for js.

`<link rel="preload" href="used-later.js" as="script">`

Answer (score 1):

You might find this wiki article interesting :  [http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript](https://web.archive.org/web/20150820074329/http://ajaxpatterns.org:80/On-Demand_Javascript)

It explains how and when to use such technique.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link appears to be dead. :(

Comment: @Eric it's because that is an ancient method of dynamically loading code :D

Answer (score 1):

One reason why your scripts could be loading so slowly is if you were running all of your scripts while loading the page, like this:

```
callMyFunctions();
```

instead of:

```
$(window).load(function() {
      callMyFunctions();
});
```

This second bit of script waits until the browser has completely loaded all of your Javascript code before it starts executing any of your scripts, making it appear to the user that the page has loaded faster.

If you're looking to enhance the user's experience by decreasing the loading time, I wouldn't go for the "loading screen" option. In my opinion that would be much more annoying than just having the page load more slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/). Its a small light weight library that you can asynchronously load your javascript with features that allow you to check if the file is loaded and execute the script in the other you specify.

Here is an example of loading jquery:

```
Modernizr.load([
  {
    load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js',
    complete: function () {
      if ( !window.jQuery ) {
            Modernizr.load('js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js');
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // This will wait for the fallback to load and
    // execute if it needs to.
    load: 'needs-jQuery.js'
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my custom solution to eliminate render-blocking JavaScript:

```
// put all your JS files here, in correct order
const libs = {
  "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
  "bxSlider": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js",
  "angular": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js",
  "ngAnimate": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-animate.min.js"
}
const loadedLibs = {}
let counter = 0

const loadAsync = function(lib) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
  http.open("GET", libs[lib], true)
  http.onload = () => {
    loadedLibs[lib] = http.responseText
    if (++counter == Object.keys(libs).length) startScripts()
  }
  http.send()
}

const startScripts = function() {
  for (var lib in libs) eval(loadedLibs[lib])
  console.log("allLoaded")
}

for (var lib in libs) loadAsync(lib)
```

In short, it loads all your scripts asynchronously, and then executes them consequently.

**Github repo**: https://github.com/mudroljub/js-async-loader

Comment: Doesn't work `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: That is CORS problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Answer (score 0):

Well, `x.parentNode` returns the HEAD element, so you are inserting the script just before the head tag. Maybe that's the problem.

Try `x.parentNode.appendChild()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this https://github.com/stephen-lazarionok/async-resource-loader. It has an example that shows how to load JS, CSS and multiple files with one shot.

Comment: It's possible to change it a little to get rid of jquery dependency

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Fetch Injection? I rolled an open source library called [fetch-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-inject) to handle cases like these. Here's what your loader might look like using the lib:

```
fetcInject([
  'js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js',
  'js/marquee.js',
  'css/marquee.css',
  'css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css',
  'css/main.css'
]).then(() => {
  'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js',
  'js/farinspace/jquery.imgpreload.min.js'
})
```

For backwards compatibility leverage feature detection and fall-back to XHR Injection or Script DOM Elements, or simply inline the tags into the page using `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a little ES6 function if somebody wants to use it in React for example

```js
import {uniqueId} from 'lodash' // optional
/**
 * @param {String} file The path of the file you want to load.
 * @param {Function} callback (optional) The function to call when the script loads.
 * @param {String} id (optional) The unique id of the file you want to load.
 */
export const loadAsyncScript = (file, callback, id) => {
  const d = document
  if (!id) { id = uniqueId('async_script') } // optional
  if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
    const tag = 'script'
    let newScript = d.createElement(tag)
    let firstScript = d.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0]
    newScript.id = id
    newScript.async = true
    newScript.src = file
    if (callback) {
      // IE support
      newScript.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (newScript.readyState === 'loaded' || newScript.readyState === 'complete') {
          newScript.onreadystatechange = null
          callback(file)
        }
      }
      // Other (non-IE) browsers support
      newScript.onload = () => {
        callback(file)
      }
    }
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(newScript, firstScript)
  } else {
    console.error(`The script with id ${id} is already loaded`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A concise answer, the explanations in the code

```
function loadScript(src) {
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = src;
//
// script.async = false; // uncomment this line and scripts will be executed in the document order, like 'defer' option
//
// script.defer = true; // uncomment this line when scripts need whole DOM and/or relative order execution is important
//
// the script starts loading as it's append to the document and dynamic script behave as “async” by default
// other scripts don’t wait for 'async' scripts, and 'async' scripts don’t wait for them
// scripts that loads first – runs first (“load-first” order)
document.body.append(script); 
}

loadScript('js/example01.js');
loadScript('js/example02.js');

/* 
the 'defer' attribute tells the browser not to wait for the script
the 'async' attribute make script to load in the background and run when ready
the 'async' and 'defer' attribute are only for external scripts
'defer' is used for scripts that need the whole DOM and/or their relative execution order is important
'async' is used for independent scripts, like counters or ads, when their relative execution order does not matter
More: https://javascript.info/script-async-defer
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [LABJS](http://labjs.com/) or [RequreJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Script loaders like `LABJS`, `RequireJS` will improve the speed and quality of your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
const dynamicScriptLoading = async (src) =>
{
    const response = await fetch(src);
    const dataResponse = await response.text();
    eval.apply(null, [dataResponse]);
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest looking into minifying the files first and see if that gives you a big enough speed boost. If your host is slow, could try putting that static content on a CDN.