# Load own script on client's site

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

Im trying to build some kind of an API in javascript. Basically, I want the client to include a script on his page and that script will load jquery, colorbox and execute a custom function which, for now, will just display a colorbox popup with a message. Of course, the script that the client includes on his page will be hosted by me.

How should this script look like in order to achieve all of the above?

Comment: You would need to load jQuery, load colorbox, then execute code. This is very doable.

Comment: If the desired outputted functionality is the same then I'd just have the user provide a json or xml file with the desired customization and parse it and apply to your existing functionality(I.E. your popup). Unless your specifically required to have the user handle js I'd keep it simple. Unless you are actually trying to write a page that is exploitable by xss in which case ignore my eariler advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = 'link to your script here';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
```

from [How to Append <script></script> in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413737/how-to-append-script-script-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The script SRC points to your own URL, just as you would using a CDN or Google Analytics.

Of course the script would expect to find some HTML, as defined by how the script already functions. Other than that - it's as if it were on your own page.