# How to include script tag while Angular2 running ?

Tags: angular

How to include this external java script library inside Angular2 page view .

I want to include this

```
 <!-- google maps javascript -->
 <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#######&sensor=true"></script>
```

so when this page is in view this library is loaded and start working .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570746/angular2-including-thirdparty-js-scripts-in-component/35570783#35570783

Comment: ok thanks, i will include this reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.** 
The Angular processor remove all script tag in the template files for a security reason.

**Alternatives:**

- Put your script in the `index.html`
- Import it directly in your component `.ts` file using `import 'path/to/file'`.

Comment: how to include googlmaps script at runtime ?

Comment: Why not `import '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#######&sensor=true'`? (In the component that need the script so the component require its dependencies)

Comment: Just see how Angular tell us to include RxJs and use the same method. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#rxjs JSFiddle or CodePen are not very good to show Angular2 app example.