# Load Javascript file into a Typescript html template (Angular2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dropzone.js

I want to know if it's possible to load a script.js into a Typescript html template in angular2? If it's not possible, how can I do and what alternatives I have? In my project, I need to call a dropzone.js script into the template dropzone.component.html. It doesn't work when I load it from this file. So how can I do if I don't want to put the script into index.html?? Thank you.

Comment: share your code snippet

Comment: If your script is in a module format (AMD, CommonJS etc.) you can dynamically (lazy) load the script with a module loader such as SystemJS.

Comment: I want to use dropzone.js (A library to drag and drop file with upload on server side) into an angular2 project. I have a SPA and I don't want to put the reference to the script in the html page index. What's the alternatives so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference this question here, I do not believe it is possible to put a script tag inside of an angular 2 template.

[angular2: including thirdparty js scripts in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570746/angular2-including-thirdparty-js-scripts-in-component)

Comment: I want to use dropzone.js (A library to drag and drop file with upload on server side) into an angular2 project. I have a SPA and I don't want to put the reference to the script in the html page index. What's the alternatives so?