# Angular 2 how to use script sanitizer

Tags: angular, html-sanitizing

I want to dynamically load external JS files depending on a condition I get by http call to a service.

I want to insert `<script>` into `app.component.html` as:

```
<script src="mysource/url"></script>
```

In my component I used `bypassSecurityTrustScript` and `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` neither works for me, my script tags get removed:

```
  <div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12 body-content'>
      <div [innerHTML]="script"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" [src] = "src"></script>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


   @Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public script: any;
  public src: any;
  public constructor(private titleService: Title, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    let x = '<script>alert("hi")</script>';
    this.script = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(x);
    this.src = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript('http://www.google.com');
  }
```

Any idea how can I use `DomSanitizer` class in this context?

Comment: were you able to implement it?

Comment: @talentedandrew no I changed my approached. I'm using Angular Universal, I decided to add the logic in cshtml views.

Comment: ok, I was also facing the similar issue . Then I used this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/postscribe , which did the trick for me.In my case, I was rendering a third party advertisement script in my angular v4 component template.You should definitely check this(library) out.

Comment: this is how I did that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606780/placing-amazon-banner-angular-v4

Comment: @talentedandrew thank you I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.src = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://www.example.com');
```

where `http://www.example.com` is the URL the script is fetched from.

Comment: Does it mean I can use `<script>` tag in app.component.html?

Comment: Right, didn't think of that. The script tag will be purged. I'll have another look later.

Comment: The `<script>` tag was mentioned in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html#!#bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl-anchor as example for `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` but that doesn't seem to make sense, because the script tag can't be added in the first place as you correctly mentioned :D

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570746/angular2-including-thirdparty-js-scripts-in-component/35570783#35570783 for how to add a script tag. You don't need the sanitizer this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I have seen that post but generating `<script>` tag feels messy, I don't like it.

Comment: I'd say the messy thing is that you want to add a script tag, not the way shown in the linked answer. If you want to include a script, then you should use `require(...)` or similar, adding a script at runtime is risky, therefore Angular doesn't provide a direct way to do it. What I show in the linked answer is the same what one would do in plain JS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413737/how-to-append-script-script-in-javascript

Comment: I completely agree with you. I have few complexity here. I have Angular Universal so index is process at server side.  Javascript I'm trying to add is not modular.  Javascript file url are decided by an api service returning e.g user is existing or not, mobile user etc