# Angular 2/4: How can I use `.js` files in certain components?

Tags: angular, tinymce-4

I'm want use `tinyMCE` editor in my project, I followed by this [docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/)
this is official documentation of integrating `tinyMCE` in `Angular 2`, but this approach is not good for me, because `ng build --prod` command generated `scripts.js` file in root folder. When user visit my site, that file would be delivered to the user while that user would never use `tinyMCE`s editor.

> How can load `.js` files of `TinyMCE` in certain component?

They somehow add script tag in their code... But I want to use different approach.

*~ apologies for grammatical mistakes :-|*

Comment: Did you try including it in component declaration part as scripts?

Comment: no I don't...how can I do that...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570746/angular2-including-thirdparty-js-scripts-in-component/35570783#35570783

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: including thirdparty js scripts in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570746/angular2-including-thirdparty-js-scripts-in-component)

Comment: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/

Comment: @Amit: sorry didn't help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try like this :

after add js file inside script

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js",
  "../node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js",
  "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.js",
  "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.js",
  "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.js"
]
```

declare tiny inside the component.ts file like below

```
import 'tinymce';
import 'tinymce/themes/modern';

import 'tinymce/plugins/table';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';

declare var tinymce: any;
```

**component.ts**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
        <!-- add tinymce attributes -->
    });
  }
```

Comment: Dear friend, I already using this approach, I'm looking for another approches )))

Comment: Dear friend, Do You edited Your answer? Now I imported all `tinymce`s files that I need into my `tinymce.component.ts`. There is no need for `scripts`... Thanks for response :-|

Answer (score 1):

You can use .js file in certain component like,

```js
ngOnInit(){
  var scriptUrl ='script.js';
  let node = document.createElement('script');
  node.src = scriptUrl;
  node.type = 'text/javascript';
  node.async = true;
  node.charset = 'utf-8';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
}
```