# Inserting Javascript into an Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular

Building an application in Angular, and we want to add a fairly complex component--in a general sense, not an Angular sense--that was completely built in Javascript, originally for a separate purpose.  The Javascript content currently spans several files; for the sake of simplicity, we'll say there's `model.js`, `library1.js`, and `library2.js`, but it's more than just those three in reality.  The function `render()` from `model.js` builds the component.

I've added `model.js` to `angular.json`, but when I go to my `model.html` page on the Angular side, the `<script>` tags don't seem to work at all, whether it's:

```
<script>
render();
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
console.log("Hello world!");
</script>
```

Is there any way to force  to work, or a better way to make this work in general?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add  tag directly under a Component HTML then it is not going to work I believe.

> `There is no Angular2 way of adding a script tag to a template.`

You can do the following in the modal.component file to dynamically add a script tag use it like this:

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {};

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
}
```

See also - [Adding scripts to the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570746/angular2-including-thirdparty-js-scripts-in-component/35570783#35570783)

In your case, you can remove the JS file from angular.json and load it at run time like this:

```
private addRenderJS() {
    const s = this.doc.createElement('script');
    s.src = '/path/my-render-lib.js';
    const head = this.doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    const s1 = this.doc.createElement('script');
    s1.type = 'text/javascript';
    s1.innerHTML = `
    render();
    `;
    head.appendChild(s);
    head.appendChild(s1);
  }
```