# Lazy load Stripe <script> to components with ElementRef

Tags: angular, webpack, stripe-payments, webpack-2

I want to lazy load a section of my website that uses Stripe for payment.  Although, I would rather not load the `<script>` tags in the index.html since it will not always be used and just add extra bandwidth.

This is a solution to that problem with Angular 2: [script tag in angular2 template / hook when template dom is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140065/script-tag-in-angular2-template-hook-when-template-dom-is-loaded) and the Angular 2 issue accompanying it: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903.

Would this be a good use case to go against conventional angular 2 practice and load it via ElementRef or is there a better way?  I'm using Webpack as my bundler.

Comment: Are you using webpack or systemJS?

Comment: I'm using Webpack. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but in case anyone comes across this like I have;

Use a service. That way the service can be replaced by injection if your app is used outside a web environment.  You can also add additional code to a) ensure that it is added only once in the application and b) return a promise so you can be sure the script is loaded before you use it;

### Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export let scripts = {
  'stripe': "https://js.stripe.com/v3/"
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExternalScriptService {

  constructor() { }

  loadStripe() : Promise<void> {
    return this.loadScript('stripe');
  }

  loadScript(key: string, url : string = null): Promise<void> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if(url == null) url = scripts[key];
      if(url == null) reject();

      let id = `app-external-${key}`;
      
      if(window.document.getElementById(id)) resolve();
      
      const scriptElement = window.document.createElement('script');
      
      scriptElement.id = id;
      scriptElement.src = url;

      scriptElement.onload = () => {
        resolve();
      };

      scriptElement.onerror = () => {
        reject();
      };

      window.document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
    });
  }
}
```

### Use in component:

```
stripeLoaded: boolean = false;

constructor(
 protected externalScriptService: ExternalScriptService
) {

externalScriptService.loadStripe().then(() => {
  this.stripeLoaded = true;
});
```

Comment: I'll add that stripe has an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-js) for the stripe.js types that includes a script loader.