# How to initialize foreign object in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with initializing of some widget.

I am doing one project(Angular 2) and there must be widget. [There it is](https://vk.com/dev/widget_comments)

In index.html I place this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?139"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    VK.init({apiId: *******, onlyWidgets: true});
</script>
```

And I have a component like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Response} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpService} from '../../services/http.service';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'post-app',
    templateUrl: 'post.component.html',
    providers: [HttpService]
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
    Post = [];
    id;
    constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute,private httpService: HttpService){
        this.id = activateRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.httpService.getOnePost(this.id).subscribe((data: Response) => this.Post=data.json());

    }
}
```

And html component:

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div [innerHTML]="Post?.Blog?.Text"></div>
</div>

<vk-component></vk-component>
```

I want to replace components with widget.

How to rewrite this on Angular 2:

```
<div id="vk_comments"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 VK.Widgets.Comments('vk_comments');
</script>
```

In agularJS I used this:

```
app.directive( 'vkComments', [
'$window',
'$timeout',
function( $window, $timeout ){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="vk_comments" ng-transclude post-url="{{url}}"></div>',
        scope: {
            readyToBind: '@'
        },
        replace: !0,
        transclude: !0,
        link: function( $scope, $element, $attr){
            $scope.$watch( 'readyToBind', function(){
                $timeout( function(){
                    $window.vkComment = VK.Widgets.Comments( 'vk_comments', { limit: 10, attach: '*', autoPublish: 1, mini: 1 }, location.href);
                }, 100 );
            } );
        }
    }
}

] );
```

But i don't know how translate it to Angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need to add the script inside of the template. The solution is to create the script manually after the template is rendered, something like

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {};

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.innerText = "VK.Widgets.Comments('vk_comments');";
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35570910/1990451) as an original answer on a similar question.