# how to write the below code in angular 2 component using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, button, paypal

```
paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function() {
            // Set up the payment here
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            // Execute the payment here
       }

    }, '#paypal-button');
```

how to implement the above code in angular 2 component and call this function in the component html file by adding the paypal button in div

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what is on your mind - do you want to have a component with button inside and bind the functions to it with `paypal.Button.render` (which I'm not familiar with to be fair)?

You can create PaypalButtonComponent and call this render action on ngOnInit (you must implement OnInit from @angular/core). I've written the following example:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'paypal-button',
        template: `<div id="paypal-button">Button</div>`
    })
    export class PaypalButtonComponent implements OnInit {
        public ngOnInit(): void {
            (window as any).paypal.Button.render({

                env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

                commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

                payment: function () {
                    // Set up the payment here
                },

                onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
                    // Execute the payment here
                }

            }, '#paypal-button');
        }
    }
```

EDIT: https://plnkr.co/edit/qaxBsnEcIPnD8oWFMj6z (check `src/app.ts`)

I've created mock `paypal.Button.render` method that mimics the desired activity and implemented two buttons: one with plain function passed and second, where I passed components method with proper `this` pointer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. But i want to add that java script in an angular 2 component typescript  and the the button should render and go to the paypal site for further payment and after the transaction it should return to the home page. I am unable to integrate the express checkout button in angular 2 and render the button and proceed to the paypal sandbox site. please help me out. Thank you.