# Cannot put ads into my Angular Dart app

Tags: angular, dart, components, adsense, angular-dart

I'm trying to put google AdSense ads into my Angular Dart app.
But if I paste it into the html of one of my components it doesn't show anything.

dashboard_component.html:

```
<head>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
        google_ad_client: "ca-pub-7364276574790830",
        enable_page_level_ads: true
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script tags added to components templates are purged by Angular for security reasons.

You need to add the script tag to `index.html`.

You can also add the script tag using imperative Dart code at runtime, for example in a lifecycle callback of an Angular component for example like I explain in [script tag in angular2 template / hook when template dom is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140065/script-tag-in-angular2-template-hook-when-template-dom-is-loaded/35570910#35570910) for TypeScript (should be easy to translate to Dart. recent Angular Dart versions don't have `nativeElement` anymore).

In a similar situation I added a unique attribute to the script tag and then used `querySelector` to check if such a script tag already exists to avoid adding it multiple times.

A script tag also has a `load` event that notifies when the script was loaded, so your code can wait for that before calling functions that are only available after the script was loaded.