# How to use JavaScript inside Angular component's HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In my Angular component, inside the HTML file, the script tags aren't working. Only HTML is being rendered but not JavaScript. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Hello, could you expand on what you need so we can help you better? Do you need to add javascript code in your component's template? If so why? Maybe there is another way to do what you need that does not require to do so. If you want to load a third party script the answers here might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140065/script-tag-in-angular2-template-hook-when-template-dom-is-loaded

Comment: I actually want to implement an Angular program that can graphically display data of csv files using bar graphs.

Answer (score 1):

To add js script tags in an Angular project you need to have the script tag created and added to the DOM programatically.

A potential solution is having a "ScriptMakerService" that you inject into your app.component or the top component of the module that requires the script. This way when the module is loaded the script is created, added to the DOM and then loaded.