# How to remove duplicated scripts in an HTML head?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending external scripts inside the head tag using the following code which I got here: [How to Append <script></script> in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413737/how-to-append-script-script-in-javascript).

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = url;
$("head").append(s);
```

It works fine, except for that sometimes, the script that I am appending is already duplicated, hence affecting the logic of the page.

Is there anyway to check for duplicate external scripts and then remove it if true?

Comment: *"and then remove it if true?"* - I don't think you want to *remove* duplicates, you want to not add duplicates in the first place.

Comment: Yes. Simply iterate through the list of scripts on the page each time'd like to add a new one, If any of them have `.src` equal to the `src` to be added,skip. `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` will get the list you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check for script with src

```
if($('script[src="'+ url +'"]').length < 1){
   $("head").append(s);
}
```

```js
var url = 'something.js';


if($('script[src="'+ url +'"]').length < 1){
   //$("head").append(s);
   alert('append');
}else{
   alert('script duplicated');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="something.js"></script>
```

Comment: @thebeast22 Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the scripts you're appending and do not add once twice. You don't want to remove scripts, you simply want to prohibit them from being added more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using following code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var exists = $('script[src="'+URL+'"]').length;
   if(exists>0){
         //already exists
   }else{
        //append new 
   }    
});
```

https://jsbin.com/cogocanoji/edit?html,css,js,console,output