# load javascript with .html() truncated

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

**Environment:**

- Version: jquery-3.1.0.js
- Agent: Chrome v51

I'd like to use ".html()" (or append) to load a pice of javascript and run it dynamic.

If the pice contains '<tr>', then the entire javascript just gone.
But if the tag is '<p>', then everything goes fine.

I know JQ use wrapMap() to auto close some tag when build buildFragment().
But it will confuse people comparing with native "innerHTML" method.

**Isn't it a jQuery bug? Or the designer meant to do this for a reason?**

**Code here**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>  
<div style="color:red;" id="out1"></div>
<div style="color:red;" id="out2"></div>
<div style="color:red;" id="out3"></div>   
<div style="color:red;" id="out4"></div>   

<script type="text/javascript">

var dom  = document.createElement('script');
var str1 = 'var a = "<tr>"; testFunc(a);';
var str2 = 'var a = "<p>"; testFunc(a);';

dom.innerHTML = str1;
$("#out1").text(dom.outerHTML);

$(dom).html(str1);
$("#out2").text(dom.outerHTML);

dom.innerHTML = str2;
$("#out3").text(dom.outerHTML);

$(dom).html(str2);
$("#out4").text(dom.outerHTML);

</script>
```

**Output here**

```
DOM generated by innerHTML
<script>var a = "<tr>"; testFunc(a);</script>

DOM generated by .html()    
<script><tr></tr></script>

DOM generated by innerHTML    
<script>var a = "<p>"; testFunc(a);</script>

DOM generated by .html()    
<script>var a = "<p>"; testFunc(a);</script>
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413737/how-to-append-script-script-in-javascript. Basically `.html()` fails it filters the javascript