# How to include a javascript file after another loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe with id="iframe"
Inside my footer of index.php, I want to include a javascript file after the iframe loads.

So far I have:

```
<script>
$('#iframe').onload = function () {
    </script>
        <script src="/js/myjsfile.js"></script>
    <script>
}
</script>
```

However, the webpage is getting angry and saying:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (for the {)
and SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
How can I include these files after load of another?

Comment: Include the file where? In main page or in iframe?

Comment: You can't have a `<script>` inside a `<script>`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
$("head").append(s);
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413737/how-to-append-script-script-in-javascript) for more information.

Hope this will help !

Comment: How would I append this if I'm trying to do this inside of the footer.php file?

Comment: It works the same, no matter if the script is inside the header.php or the footer.php. If you put this into jQuery('#iframe').ready tag, script will be loaded after your iframe will be ready too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) and detect the **load** event for the iframe.

```js
$('#iframe').on('load', function(e) {
    $.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js', function() {
        // library is loaded. Now I can start to use.;
        console.log('Now the library is loaded!');
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<iframe id="iframe" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" style="width: 200px;height: 200px"></iframe>
```

A different approach can be based on adding the script element dynamically like in:

```js
$('#iframe').on('load', function(e) {
  $('head').append($('<script/>', {src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js'}));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<iframe id="iframe" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" style="width: 200px;height: 200px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why do I need to use ajax?

Comment: @GeorgeChen Answer updated. You can create the script element on the fly and append it to the header section of your html. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can inject a script tag on iframe load like this.

```
        <script>
         $('#iframe').on('load', function() {
             var script = document.createElement('script');
             script.src = '/js/myjsfile.js';
             document.body.appendChild(script);
         });
        </script>
```

Comment: `$('#iframe').onload` is invalid

Comment: My bad, copied his from up above, I fixed it.