# instagram embed doesn't work at first when dynamically appending into a page, but then works after refresh

Tags: instagram, embed

Go to:
http://staging2.ju.blog.kylebaker.io/

click hamburger

click 'timeline'

instagram embeds show only the gray logo and don't load fully. embed.js doesn't seem to load when watching in the network tab.

Now, click refresh.

Now, everything loads. embed.js is there.

:/

You can notice that an older version on http://staging.ju.blog.kylebaker.io works fine--this seems to obviously be because it's an entirely new page load (which I want to avoid).

Some potentially relevant code this theme relies on to load this page "into" the page:

```js
    L: function(url, f, err) {
        if (url == xhrUrl) {
            return false;
        }
        xhrUrl = url;
        if (xhr) {
            xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function(data) {
                f(data);
                xhrUrl = '';
            },
            error: function(a, b, c) {
                if (b == 'abort') {
                    err && err()
                } else {
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
                xhrUrl = '';
            }
        });
    },
    HS: function(tag, flag) {
        var id = tag.data('id') || 0,
            url = tag.attr('href'),
            title = tag.attr('title') + " - " + $("#config-title").text();

        if (!$('#preview').length || !(window.history && history.pushState)) location.href = url;
        Diaspora.loading()
        var state = {d: id, t: title, u: url};
        Diaspora.L(url, function(data) {
            if (!$(data).filter('#single').length) {
                location.href = url;
                return
            }
            switch (flag) {
                case 'push':
                    history.pushState(state, title, url)
                    break;
                case 'replace':
                    history.replaceState(state, title, url)
                    break;
            }
            document.title = title;
            $('#preview').html($(data).filter('#single'))
            switch (flag) {
                case 'push':
                    Diaspora.preview()
                    break;
                case 'replace':
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
                    Diaspora.loaded()
                    break;
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                Diaspora.player();
                $('#top').show();
                comment = $("#gitalk-container");
                if (comment.data('ae') == true){
                    comment.click();
                }
            }, 0)
        })
    },
    preview: function() {
        // preview toggle
        $("#preview").one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function() {
            var previewVisible = $('#preview').hasClass('show');
            if (!!previewVisible) {
                $('#container').hide();
            }else{
                $('#container').show();
            }
            Diaspora.loaded();
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#preview').addClass('show');
            $('#container').data('scroll', window.scrollY);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#preview').css({
                    'position': 'static',
                    'overflow-y': 'auto'
                });
            }, 500);
        }, 0);
    },
```

(for full file, see: https://github.com/Fechin/hexo-theme-diaspora/blob/master/source/js/diaspora.js)

I see the script tag loaded in the DOM; why isn't it loading? Feels like it must be something simple I'm missing... It's 4am and I've been working non-stop.

(please ignore the dust, this is a small side-project work-in-progress with many small things broken.)

Things I've tried:

- adding the code to load embed.js manually in the page. (no change--I then see embed.js is loaded, but it doesn't have an impact on the result)
- editing the URL to include "http:" before the "//insta..." url (as
  recommended in some answers elsewhere for some people) (no change)
- `window.instgrm.Embeds.process()` it seems the `instgrm` object no longer exists. (no change)

Seems to be related to however this is being injected via jquery, but I'm a little confused as to specifics, figured I'd ask the world and make a space for the answer to exist for the next poor soul.

Note that because of what I've tried, the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444920/jquery-appending-instagrams-blockquote-embedding-dynamically-doesnt-work) do not seem to be helpful or relevant, though maybe it's just me blanking at 4am.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was, indeed, the things I had already addressed, I just missed some rendering details of getting changes to stick. jQuery executing and stripping the script tags seems to have been the source the problem, and calling `window.instgrm.Embeds.process()` at the appropriate time, after making sure that the `embeds.js` script was requested in the right place/at the right time, was enough to fix the issue seen above. Part of the confusion was using hexo, which uses ejs in node, which doesn't really seem to allow client-executing inline JS in ejs template files themselves, silently.

Comment: Had trouble getting instagram embeds to load properly in a react/gatsby SPA, since navigation doesn't trigger processing. This was exactly what I needed 

Comment: makes my day. this is the kind of thing you always hope for when you type out this kind of obscure stuff into the ether. cheers!

Comment: I have a simple Instagram embed in a next.js project. I have the same issue. It does not work on the first load but works on refresh. Any suggestions?

Comment: This was 5 years ago. Read the question and answer. Try to apply it. If it doesn't work, figure out why or move on to another source. If you want to hire me to work on your specific problem, let me know.