# Load script from a variable at runtime

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ajax` call which gets a string contains script from the backend. Now I want to add this string to a script tag at runtime.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Users/_getScript",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        script = data;
        console.log(script);
    }
});
```

say `script` is a global variable which now contains code from backend.

> Note: There is no URL from which I want to load external js. I want to add a string variable.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"add string to script tag"*? Sounds like what you want is [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: I'm getting the js code through an ajax call in string now I want to add this string to a script tag.

Comment: No need if you use `$.getScript`. If you are returning valid js it will get evaluated immediately

Comment: @charlietfl but ` $.getScript("demot.js");` takes an external js file as an argument, not a variable. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Does not have to be js file ...just has to be valid js returned

Comment: Example using `.txt` file http://plnkr.co/edit/tI6x43jMtcYH9DqnxBKf?p=preview

Comment: I think you return your script with script tag from c# method. And use `insertBefore()`. This way you can insert that script tag in your body tag. This is what you want.?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to use `ajax` for now, it seems that  `$.getScript` also loads external js

Comment: $.getScript is ajax...jQuery just evaluates the code for you and any functions or variables are available at the point the callback gets called and any time after that point. What exactly is it you want to do with  this code?

Comment: @charlietfl my backend function is returning CS script say `<script type = "CS"> //script goes here </script>` in a varibale through ajax call, all I want is to add this variable to my aspx page at runtime.

Comment: You don't need the script tag. Once script is evaluated it is in memory and available any time after. The script tag does nothing after the code is compiled

Comment: so you are saying is that all I need to do is call `$.getScript(myvariable)` and the script will be appended there?

Comment: No.. see my demo example above. I added a setInterval to show you that it is available for the life of the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162315/discussion-between-habib-ur-rehman-and-charlietfl).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Append <script></script> in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413737/how-to-append-script-script-in-javascript)

Comment: @HabibUrRehman If your returned string contains `script` tag then simply use `$(data).appendTo('head');`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `insertAfter` or `insertBefore` to append your script. If you want to execute your script, use `$.getScript()`.

```
$("<yourscript>").insertAfter("<any element you want your script to be added after>")

$("<yourscript>").insertBefore("<any element you want your script to be added before>")
```