# Execute Script tag using JS instead of PHP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, function

I have a case in php, where I execute `<script>` tag of Adsense, if the userAgent is not BOT, but for some good reason I want to execute it using JS.

Helper Function:

```
function detectBottypes() {
        $userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        if(!empty($userAgent) and preg_match('~(bot|crawl|google|lighthouse|spider|feedparser|crawler|pinterest)~i', $userAgent)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

in View:

```
    @if( Request::is('photo/*') && detectBottypes()==false )

        <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        </script>

    @endif
```

Above, if request is photo/* and not bot then it is rendered in view, but I want it to be rendered in either of cases but only executed for the specific case.
I have the case of JS

```
       window.onload = function () {
            var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            if (agent.indexOf('bot') != -1) { 
              // ******* Execute here ********
            }
            else {
               
            }
       }
```

**Reason why I want:** I cache the view file to skip the load on server, so if the page is first crawled by Bot(Google) it is cached without the above case of Adsense Script ( Ad is not loaded to Bot) but since it is cached if later it is viewed by real user, the cached version without Ads is shown which I do not want, so preferred to be with JS

Comment: What do you mean by _"I want it to be rendered in either of cases but only executed for the specific case"_?  That script from Google does not appear to have any particular initialization method to call, so presumably it does its job, as soon as the script has loaded. I think what you probably want to do, is dynamically create a `script` element and append it to the document. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9413737/1427878

Comment: @CBroe see, I added the reason at the end. Hope you understand

Comment: The cache doesn't matter, you can still append/include the adsense scripts to your (cached) HTML with javascript when the visitor is not a bot.

Comment: Okay so then you want the code that checks the UA to execute in _any_ case, but only have it load the Google script when the condition matches. Dynamically create and append the script element for the Google ads then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically load a script with something like:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (agent.indexOf('bot') != -1) { 
       var scriptTag = document.createElement('script'); 
       scriptTag.src = 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js';
       scriptTag.async = true;
       scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
       scriptTag.crossorigin = 'anonymous';
       document.head.prepend(scriptTag);
    } else {
    
    }
}
```

This should cause the browser to download and run the script. However there's a broader question on your use of caching. It may be simpler if you cache two versions of the content and serve each one based on the UA, if that is an option.