# Load jquery if its not already loaded and use local version if no connection is available

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

Here is my current code. Is there any way to load a local copy of the jquery lib, if `script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"` fails? And is this script loaded asynchronous? Or will it freeze the ui thread until loaded?

Comment: have a look that this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
<script src="cdn.jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/local/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: doesnt IE throw an exception when jQuery is undefined?

Comment: My problem is that sometimes jquery is already loaded, regardless of if the user is connected to the internet. Could i add another `||`? Something like this: `<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"><\/script>||document.write('<script src="/local/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>`

Comment: Just load it before that snippet and if it fails then it will load the local version. See my edit.

Comment: But now it will load `<script src="cdn.jquery.js"></script>` even if another version is already loaded, right?

Comment: You mean if the script is loaded in cache?

Comment: Im trying to make a fix for a page that adds usercontrols to some pages. And if a certain usercontrol is added, jquery is included in that. So sometimes it will be loaded twice, which results in some errors. Sorry for beeing unclear

Comment: Why not just load jQuery in the head? I don't get it... Otherwise consider using AMD modules.

Comment: Some designer prefered to load all scripts at the bottom of the page. But ill try to move em. Thanks

Comment: Bottom of the page is fine too just wrap everything in DOM ready in that case