# Load file local or from cdn

Tags: jquery, html, local

I have a pretty simple question that I had in my mind today. I'm linking to jquery locally, from my pc in case I don't have internet connection but I was wondering if there is a way to check if there is internet connection and if so, load jquery from CDN. Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you check `HTTP Status code` and load file accordingly?

Comment: [A similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12474964/6551577) was answered a few years ago. Please take a look at it.

Comment: may be try an ajax after load with some timeout? If the particular url does not load after specified amount of time, then include the local js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this CDN fallback:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

HTML5 boilerplate is using this technique: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/index.html

Please check this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Pure html solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test CDN fallback</title>
</head>

<body>
  <object data="https://cdn.invented.com/something" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  </object>
  <!-- in your case -->
    <!-- <object data="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
      <script src="/local/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    </object> -->
</body>
</html>
```