# Socket.io client can't connect after first attempt

Tags: connection, client, socket.io

Socket.io connects to the Java Netty server. If socket.io tries to connect the server while it's down, 404 will be ocurred. So Javascript console says:

```
http://mylocalhost.com/socket.io/1/?t=1354790544338 - Failed to load resource
```

After this the socket.io connection dies completely. It won't try to connect again because of that 404...

How should I handle this? I tried to set an interval which would try to connect every five seconds, put the server online, but it won't try to connect because of that error.

After page reload it works normally. Is there a way in socket.io for observing when the server is online again and then connect to it? What could be a proper solution?

I've made sure that the socket.io.js client javscript is loaded correctly, and my understanding of what's happening is this:

1. socket.io starts handshakes, and socket.socket.connecting is set to true
2. request to http://mylocalhost.com/socket.io/1/?t=1354790544338 causes 404 because the server is down
3. this is an error, but socket.socket.connecting remains as true, which causes next reconnect attempts to fail, because it won't try to reconnect if it thinks that it's already trying to reconnect

I've tried calling `disconnect()` before trying to reconnect, and it sets reconnecting as false, but when there's no connected socket and I call `disconnect()`, it throws `"Cannot call method 'close' of undefined"`.

What could be a proper solution to get that reconnecting as false, kinda "reset" socket.io to be ready for next connection attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Setting handlers for all of the possible `socket.io` client errors *seemed* to fix this problem for me*. That includes:

```
'connect_error'
'connect_timeout'
'reconnect_error'
'reconnect_failed'
'error'
```

After a bit of experimenting, the 'error' handler seems to be the important one for preventing the 404 from stopping everything else.

*seemed to fix, because I can't reliably reproduce it in my local test setup. Would be good to know if adding these handlers fixes the problem for anyone else.

Comment: Even for me it's the error event which gets thrown: just listening to it doesn't fix for me. So inside the handler I tryed to reconnect: it doesn't work (I don't see the http call in firebug). It's interesting to note that if I change the port in the code that reconnects, it tries to do so...

Answer (score -1):

The socket.io file it tries to request contains actual script to use in JS. This file is served by your Java server. So when you request this file - it will fail to load, that is why you see 404 error.

Since file is not loaded, anything related to sockets that comes from that file wont be available.
So what you want to try to do, is to catch scenario when script file is not loaded. Check here: [load scripts asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously)

So you have to try to load this script asynchronously, and check on status after load. If it failed or did not responded in time - flush request handle, and request again after some delay.

Once file will be successfully loaded, you can start using JS functions to call connect and so on.

Comment: No the file is loaded he is correct it is because it is trying to reconnect.