# How to Further Optimize WP Site

Tags: wordpress, optimization

Need some help optimizing my WP site. I think I've done a pretty good job so far:

1. reduced image sizes
2. optimized DB
3. running W3 Cache
4. Cloutflare (basic) CDN (currently disabled until site goes live)

I've gone as far as i can on my own.

Can anyone suggest further optimizations steps I might take to speed up this site?  It's on a shared host, so anything else i can do to reduce load time will make a big difference.

www.livingaha.com  is the landing page and
www.livingaha.com/blog   is the blog

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: * Try to use colors and design in html
* gzip and compress your css and javascipt
* Remove unwanted comments, css scripts and html from the pages 
* use cache for big files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only so much you can do on shared hosting but there are always things you can do to tweak the performance but it's whether or not that tiny performance increase will be worth the time. Cost wise it'd probably be better to upgrade the server rather than you spending time tweaking things slightly. That aside, here's some small tips that could shave a few secs of the loading time:

- Any php references that **you know for a fact** will never change
  (such as site name) the meta title tag `<?php echo bloginfo('name');
  ?>` change to a static HTML reference in a child theme.
- Minify all JS and CSS.
- Load js asynchronously.
- Look at lazy load for images.

Apart from that, there's not much else you can do.

Comment: thanks Scott. I'll look at the minify and the lazy load. How would it do the async js?  Also, gtmetrix.com suggests i   "This page has 16 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one. This page has 9 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one."   Any idea how i would go about that?         thanks again for your help

Comment: I've been in your position before and there comes a point where you just have to upgrade to a slightly better server (or even shared) to get a performance hike.
Save writing the same solution have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously
Reference the stylesheets - if they're something you control and or don't mind maintaining, merge them and place a copy on your own site. If not, you can't really do much about CSS hosted elsewhere.