# Angular routing and dynamically loading controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

We are creating a single page app with Angular routing.
The problem is that the Javascript with the controller(s) need to be referenced.
I want the js file to be downloaded dynamically on demand.

Is it mandatory to use a system like RequireJS ? Is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is just a wrapper over pure JS to make a system that's defined in its documentation (MVC, two-way binding, directive and so on).  So, you can download the JS and bind the controller defined in the file to the angular app (`ng-app`). You don't need to use RequireJS to load the file, rather you can use pure JS to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Most people use requirejs but you can do it in pure JS.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously)