# Need suggestion about ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have small issue - I'm making ajax query to transfer data to another php file and once query success I need to load one script.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'promote.php',    
    data: { country:country },    
    success: function() {
        //What to do here?
    }
});
```

The script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var var1 = "d1dtGWhrOaxxUVCy%2FNjJwkpd9lCj%2FGijAGXS5d7LYPU%3D";
    var var2 = "jn9drdklwlr5hjYc2eHTCaXRjdpHDqhaqL5LXpsyc54%3D";
    var var3 = "E770DuKV8GKaHhaZO%2B%2F9sPzUI9mAUFVRrxRTH75pHvA%3D";
    var var4 = "LhWNAMH8CgveH%2FqRHKxqg8ebEVZKTX4pQw3pp5wTRl8%3D";
    var network = "xxxxxxx";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxx/js/xx.js"></script>
```

So any suggestions how could I load this script when ajax query success? I need to do that in in this file, please don't suggest putting script in other file and loading from it. Would that be possible?

Comment: you load this script from the ajax url i guess, right?

Comment: Usually you provide a callback function for the success. The signature for the function is: `Function(PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)`

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously) can give you an answer.

Comment: Thanks for help. I've got answer, sorry for a bit dumb question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'promote.php',    
data: { country:country },    
success: function() {

 var script='<script type="text/javascript">';
     script+='var var1 = "d1dtGWhrOaxxUVCy%2FNjJwkpd9lCj%2FGijAGXS5d7LYPU%3D";';
     script+='var var2 = "jn9drdklwlr5hjYc2eHTCaXRjdpHDqhaqL5LXpsyc54%3D"';
     script+='var var3 = "E770DuKV8GKaHhaZO%2B%2F9sPzUI9mAUFVRrxRTH75pHvA%3D"';
     script+='var var4 = "LhWNAMH8CgveH%2FqRHKxqg8ebEVZKTX4pQw3pp5wTRl8%3D"';
     script+='var network = "xxxxxxx"';
     script+='</script>';
     script+='<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxx/js/xx.js"></script>';
     $("head").append(script);
}
});
```

Comment: Btw. When I place this code It somehow doesn't work, but displays raw code in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for append the  tag:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
$("head").append(s);
```