# How do i get callback after all scripts loaded?

Tags: javascript

How do I know all scripts loaded in below code?

```
function loadExternalResource(url, type, callback){
    var _css, _script, _document = document;
    if(type === 'css'){
        _css = _document.createElement("link");
        _css.type = 'text/css';
        _css.rel = 'stylesheet';
        _css.href = URL;
        _document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(_css);
    }
    else if(type === "js")
    {
            _script = _document.createElement("script");
            _script.type = "text/javascript";
            _script.src = URL;
            _script.onload = callback;
            _document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(_script);
    }
}

//Loading All Css Here
loadExternalResource('/css/common.css','css');
loadExternalResource('/css/main.css','css');

//Load All Scripts here
loadExternalResource('/js/general.js','js', function(){
    alert('general js loaded');
});
loadExternalResource('/js/validation.js','js', function(){
    alert('validation js loaded');
});
loadExternalResource('/js/core.js','js', function(){
    alert('core js loaded');
});
loadExternalResource('/js/library.js','js', function(){
    alert('library js loaded');
});
```

In Above Code, I am getting callback for every single js file loaded, but how to know all scripts loaded here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load scripts asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously)

Comment: You can register a handler to the "on load" event of those scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea using promises.  The general idea is that you change the function `loadExternalResource()` to return a promise that is resolved when the resource is loaded.  You can then collect any number of these promises into an array and use `Promise.all()` to see when all of them are done.  For convenience, I put this functionality into a master function called `loadMultipleExternalResources()` that loads an array of URLs.

Here's the code:

```
function loadExternalResource(url, type){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var tag;
        if (!type) {
            var match = url.match(/\.([^.]+)$/);
            if (match) {
                type = match[1];
            }
        }
        if (!type) {
            type = "js";       // default to js
        }

        if (type === 'css'){
            tag = document.createElement("link");
            tag.type = 'text/css';
            tag.rel = 'stylesheet';
            tag.href = url;
        }
        else if (type === "js")
        {
            tag = document.createElement("script");
            tag.type = "text/javascript";
            tag.src = url;
        }
        if (tag) {
            tag.onload = function() {resolve(url);};
            tag.onerror = function() {reject(url);};
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
        }
    });
}

function loadMultipleExternalResources(itemsToLoad) {
    var promises = itemsToLoad.map(function(url) {
        return loadExternalResource(url);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);    
}

//Loading All Css Here
var urls = ['/css/common.css', '/css/main.css', '/js/general.js', '/js/validation.js', '/js/core.js','js', '/js/library.js'];

loadMultipleExternalResources(urls).then(function() {
    // all these resources loaded here
});
```

Or, using your callback scheme, you could manually keep a counter of the number of files that are loaded:

```
function loadExternalResource(url, type, callback){
    var tag;

    ++loadExternalResource.cnt;
    if (type === 'css'){
        tag = _document.createElement("link");
        tag.type = 'text/css';
        tag.rel = 'stylesheet';
    }
    else if (type === "js")
    {
        tag = _document.createElement("script");
        tag.type = "text/javascript";
        tag.src = url;
    }
    if (tag) {
        tag.onload = function() {
            --loadExternalResource.cnt;
            callback(loadExternalResource.cnt, url);
        }
        tag.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
    }
}

loadExternalResource.cnt = 0;

//Loading All Css Here
loadExternalResource('/css/common.css','css', checkAllDone);
loadExternalResource('/css/main.css','css', checkAllDone);

//Load All Scripts here
loadExternalResource('/js/general.js','js', checkAllDone);
loadExternalResource('/js/validation.js','js', checkAllDone);
loadExternalResource('/js/core.js','js', checkAllDone);
loadExternalResource('/js/library.js','js', checkAllDone);

function checkAllDone(cnt, url) {
    if (cnt === 0) {
        // all scripts and CSS files loaded now
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a means of doing it using your callback scheme too.

Answer (score 1):

May you use jQuery?

With [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) is quite simple. You just do

```
$.when($getScript("file1.js"), 
       $getScript("file2.js"), 
       $getScript("file3.js")).
       done(function(){
          //code here
       }
);
```