# How can I determine whether jQuery is fully initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I'm writing a bookmarklet using jQuery. It looks like `javascript:document.write('<script src="path/to/loader.js"></script>')`, and `loader.js` does the initializing stuffs:

```
check_the_environment();

document.head.innerHTML='<meta charset=utf-8>';
document.body.innerHTML='(the webpage)';

var jq=document.createElement('script');
jq.src='path/to/jquery.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(jq);

function load_core() {
    if(window.$)
        eval('(core js code)');
    else
      setTimeout(load_core,50);
}
load_core();
```

The loader loads the core javascript code after the jQuery is available.

But sometimes I get this error in my core code:

`$(...).on is not a function`

It seems that jQuery was still initializing itself although `$` variable is setted.

So, I need to wait for jQuery to be **completely initialized** before the loader loads the core code. How can I do that?

The traditional way of using `$(document).ready(...)` is infeasible, as jQuery is being loaded **after** the webpage is ready.

Here is a minimal Python code to check whether the solution is working:

```
import cherrypy

mod='''
var htmlroot=document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

function load_core() {
  if(window.jQuery)
    jQuery(function(){
        alert($(document).on);
    });
  else
    setTimeout(load_core,10);
}

if(!document.head)
  htmlroot.appendChild(document.createElement('head'));

var jquery=document.createElement('script');
jquery.src='http://libs.useso.com/js/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(jquery);

load_core();
'''

class Website:
    @cherrypy.expose()
    def mod(self,_time):
        return mod

    @cherrypy.expose()
    def index(self):
        return '''<a href="javascript:document.write('<script src=/mod/'+(+new Date())+' ></script>')">Mod</a>'''

cherrypy.quickstart(Website(),'/');
```

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously

Comment: First thing to try is swap `window.$` for `window.jQuery`

Answer (score 2):

The right and foolproof way would be:

```
jQuery(function(){
    // code
});
```

Since jQuery may be loaded in [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode the `$` var may not have been initialized.

For the sake of productivity the following can also be used to have access to `$` var inside the `jQuery` scope.

```
jQuery(function($){
    // you can use $ without worrying about conflicts now
});
```

Comment: `jQuery` will still be undefined as script is loaded asynchronously..Will have to play with `onload` event I suppose...

Comment: that solution is not working as the code inside `jQuery(function($){})` is NEVER being executed. see my question for a small program to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check type of $ as below

```
if(typeof $ == "function"){
    //Jquery loaded
}
```