# Get progress of script tag evaluation?

Tags: javascript, dom, onload, evaluate, onload-event

I have a large javascript from a webpack build being loaded as such: 
`<script src="application.bundle.js"></script>`

I want to add a progress bar while the script loads. In chrome dev tools timeline, I can see that most of the load time is spent here: "Evaluate Script", understandably so. Is there any way to get progress or at the very least a done event to know when the script is done evaluating?

I could do something in the application script like `window.appLoaded = true` and look for that periodically. Is there a way to do this without modifying the application script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a callback after the file is loaded, I suggest you load it asynchronously with a function call that uses a callback function upon completion.

You could put up a progress spinner before calling the loader function, with the callback taking it down. Something like this:

```
function myLoadScript( ) {
    showMyProgress();
    loadScript( 'application.bundle.js', hideMyProgress );
}
```

This page shows a few ways to [load scripts asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously). A generic `loadScript()` function is shown there.

Comment: Assuming he's done his metrics right, it looks like the majority of the time is in evaluating the script, not downloading it; would asynchronicity still take effect during the compile step?

Comment: Using the loadScript function from that link appears to invoke the callback after the script is evaluated... at least in Chrome. Thank you @terrymorse.

Comment: @meta-meta glad I could help, do you accept my answer?