# Twitter widget inside WebView in React Native

Tags: twitter, webview, react-native

I'm trying to load a Twitter widget inside a `WebView` in my React Native app, but it seems that my injected Javascript is not working for some reason.

What I'm doing is loading Twitter script asynchronously (function taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719185/552669)), then executing [`twttr.widgets.load()`](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization) function when script is loaded in order to draw the widget.

Is it possible to do it, or am I trying an impossible with default `Webview` component?

Here is my code:

```
render() {
    let utils = ' \
      function loadScript(src, callback) { \
        var s, r, t; \
        r = false; \
        s = document.createElement("script"); \
        s.type = "text/javascript"; \
        s.src = src; \
        s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() { \
          if ( !r && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "complete") ) { \
            r = true; \
            callback(); \
          } \
        }; \
        t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; \
        t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t); \
      } \
    ';

    let twitter = ' \
      loadScript("//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js", function () { \
        twttr.widgets.load(); \
      }); \
    ';

    let JS = utils + twitter;

    let source = '<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="es"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">8 TED Talks to inspire projects with kids: <a href="https://twitter.com/TEDTalks/status/758116657638309896">https://twitter.com/TEDTalks/status/758116657638309896</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/TEDTalks/status/758116657638309896">pic.twitter.com/HMmYAeP7Km</a></p>&mdash; TED Talks (@TEDTalks) <a href="https://twitter.com/TEDTalks/status/758116657638309896">27 de julio de 2016</a></blockquote>';

    return (
      <WebView
        source={{html: source}}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavascript={ JS }
      />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like loading scripts inside a WebView is not working (I don't know why). So to make it work, I need to load Twitter's script using script tag and concatenating it to my HTML code.

```
render() {

    let JS = '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>';

    let source = JS + '<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="es"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">8 TED Talks to inspire projects with kids: <a href="https://twitter.com/TEDTalks/status/758116657638309896">https://twitter.com/TEDTalks/status/758116657638309896</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/TEDTalks/status/758116657638309896">pic.twitter.com/HMmYAeP7Km</a></p>&mdash; TED Talks (@TEDTalks) <a href="https://twitter.com/TEDTalks/status/758116657638309896">27 de julio de 2016</a></blockquote>';

    return (
      <WebView
        source={{html: source}}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
      />
    );
}
```

Comment: This answer is from 2016. Things have changed on React ecosystem since them.

Comment: Could you please share what have changed and what is the latest way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I hacked it together like this and it mostly works, although height isn't variable which isn't ideal:

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactNative from "react-native"

const { View, WebView, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } = ReactNative

export default class EmbeddedTweet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      embedHtml: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setupEmbed()
  }

  setupEmbed() {
    let tweetUrl =
      "https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=" + encodeURIComponent(this.props.url)
    fetch(tweetUrl, { method: "GET", headers: { Accepts: "application/json" } }).then(
      resp => {
        resp.json().then(json => {
          let html = json.html
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            embedHtml: html,
          })
        })
      }
    )
  }

  renderLoading() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loadingWrap}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  renderEmbed() {
    if (this.state.embedHtml) {
      let html = `<!DOCTYPE html>\
        <html>\
          <head>\
            <meta charset="utf-8">\
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\
            </head>\
            <body>\
              ${this.state.embedHtml}\
            </body>\
        </html>`
      return (
        <View style={styles.webviewWrap}>
          <WebView source={{ html: html }} style={styles.webview} />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={[styles.container, { height: this.props.height || 300 }, this.props.style]}
      >
        {this.renderLoading()}
        {this.renderEmbed()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  loadingWrap: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#999",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  webviewWrap: {
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: "#999",
  },
  webview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})
```