# React native - embed Twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter, react-native

I created a react native app. Want i want to implement is a page that shows a user's twitter feed. If you look online, twitter offers this [feature](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/user). However, the twitter example uses  tag, and that is not supported in react-native. Does anyone know how to embed twitter feed in react native ?

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
  href="https://twitter.com/twitterdev">
Tweets by @TwitterDev
</a>
```

Comment: try this: https://github.com/capaj/react-tweet-embed

Comment: @ChandraKumar This is for ReactJS, not React Native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no React Native implementation for twitter feed.

You have 3 options:

1. Implement it yourself using twitter API;
2. Use WebView as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610431/twitter-widget-inside-webview-in-react-native?rq=1);
3. You can also wrap native [Twitter Kit for iOS](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/overview) and [Twitter Kit for Android](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/overview) as described in [Native UI Components](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2023**
now have an easy option to display tweets, just pass a url with the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-twitter-preview

and usage:

```
<TwitterPreview
  url={'https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1636162726140493825'}
/>
```