# Reload external script when clicked button JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have blog post that use ajax for load more and `mansory.js` for display the block.

but when i load more the data my interface broken since its use `mansory.js`.

how to make ajax load + reload/refresh the `mansory.js` again?...

here my `index.html`

```
....
<script src="plugins/masonry/masonry.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click','#load-more',function(){
       var id = $(this).data('id');
       $("#load-more").html("Loading....");
       $.ajax({
          ....
       });
   });
});
</script>
....
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the following method right after post is ajax requested to re-layout the masonry.

```
$grid.masonry()
```

or if using vanilla javascript

```
msnry.layout()
```