# Loading library objects using async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I've been using @zzzzBov's [fantastic `loadScript()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719185/9068081) to load JS libraries using Promises.
However, it becomes tedious and messy to chain together Promises for all of the loaded libraries. I'd like to switch to an `async/await` solution, but—since `loadScript()` function doesn't return the usable library objects I need—this isn't as straightforward as using `.then()` at a first glance.

The function returns a load `Event`, which I `await`. So my initial approach would be to just define some useless constants as the Promise returns, and then reference them in an if statement:

```js
let loadedGlobalObject: any;
const lib1Loaded: Event = await loadScript(lib1URL);
const lib2Loaded: Event = await loadScript(lib2URL);

if (lib1Loaded && lib2Loaded) { // Makes this block dependent upon the await statements
   loadedGlobalObject = (window as any).globalObject;
   console.log(loadedGlobalObject);
}
```

Is this correct form? I don't know how to "invoke" the `await` statements; an if statement was my first guess. So I'm wondering if this is the best solution, or if there is a more efficient/accepted technique (I know that I could substitute the libXLoaded constants into the if statement, but I'm going for readability).

Comment: Could you use `Promise.all()`?

Comment: What do you need those "useless constants" and especially the if statement for at all?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do - you want to `await` the loading of your libraries, and access the global objects only once they are loaded. What about something like this:

```
try {
  async function loadLibs () {
    const lib1Event: Event = await loadScript(lib1Url);

    let loadedGlobalObject: any;
    loadedGlobalObject = (window as any).globalObject;
    console.log(loadedGlobalObject);
  }

  loadLibs();
  
catch (err) {
  console.log('Error loading script: ', err);
}
```

The `loadScript()` function `reject`s if there was an error while loading the script, so you can wrap your code in a `try...catch`. Otherwise, it `resolve`s and you can access it's global object.

Note that you can only call `await` within a function marked as `async`.

Comment: In this form, you don't really need to store the Event response at all.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I didn't understand `async/await` at all. I had thought that the `await`ed constants were reactive, and lines referencing them were run only after their Promises resolved; instead, it's just the rest of the function that waits.

For error-handling, as @dwosk answered, you can use a try-catch, although I wasn't concerned about this. As @Rezaa91 commented, I could have used an `await Promise.all([])`, except for that I'm loading dependencies in order. And, now that I understand `await` statements better and as @dwosk and @Bergi noted, I don't need to define those constants.

In summary, my modified code (with `Promise.all()` added for fun) looks like this:

```js
let loadedGlobalObject: any;
await Promise.all([loadScript(dependency1), loadScript(dependency2)]);
await loadScript(library1);
// Will have been loaded by now.
loadedGlobalObject = (window as any).globalObject;
console.log(loadedGlobalObject);
```