# How to call anonymus function from string

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have string containg anonymus function definition, but how i can call this. Lets say function is like so:

```
var fn_str = "function(){ alert('called'); }";
```

Tried eval, but got an error that function must have a name.

```
eval(fn_str).apply(this); // SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
```

Comment: You call `eval` with `a` while the function string is in `fn_str`. that won't work this way...

Comment: Sorry, i used a in firebug console for shortness but forgot to change this, good eye though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use *Immediately Invoked Function Expression*:

```
var fn_str = "function(){ alert('called'); }";
eval('(' + fn_str +')();');
```

[Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/440739/601179)

Another way is to use to a `Function` object (If you have the function body string):

```
var func = new Function("alert('called')");
func.apply(this);
```

Comment: Already figured out, but thanks! Accept/+1 for quick response :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create functions from strings using the Function constructor:

```
var fn = new Function("arg1", "alert('called ' + arg1);");
fn.apply(this)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: Put function in parentheses

```
var a = "(function(){ alert('called'); })";
eval(a).apply(this);
```

Comment: You don't need to write use `apply` you can use *Immediately Invoked Function Expressions** as I answered.

Comment: I know that syntax, but i cant pass an object as a parameter that way(without parsing an object to string). Or can i?

Comment: What did you mean in that comment, I didn't understand it. What do you need?

Comment: Sample code:

`var fn = "function(object, cb) { /* Do something with the object */ }";
var obj = { param: value, param2: value2 };
eval('('+fn')').apply(this, [obj]);`

Comment: Can you get the function body? without the `function(object, cb){ ` part

Comment: I could if i'll parse the string and strip `function(){` and `}` from it, but i alrealy solved my case. Thanks anyways