# javascript anonymous function

Tags: javascript

```
function (){
    alert('a function');
}
```

when i put it on the firebug javascript control. it shows **function statement requires a name**

```
(function (){
    alert('a function');
}())
```

when i put the above it shows ok.

```
function (){
    alert('a function');
}()
```

it also shows  **function statement requires a name** and doesn't execute the function. why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do parentheses surrounding a JavaScript object/function/class declaration mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/442408/1113426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function (){
    alert('a function');
}
```

is a function statement, so it requires a name.

```
(function (){
    alert('a function');
}())
```

The `()` change the statement to an expression, so it's OK.

And you could also use the below ways.

```
(function (){
    alert('a function');
})();

!function (){
    alert('a function');
}();

+function (){
    alert('a function');
}();
```

Comment: They just change the statement to an expression.