# Invoke function in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do parentheses surrounding a JavaScript object/function/class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m)

Why following code does not work

```
function func() {
    document.writeln("HELLO");
}();
```

UPDATE:
Why in following example O should not use parentesis around "function{}"?

```
var v = function() {
   return "HELLO";
}();
```

document.writeln(v);
​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either this:

```
function func() {
    document.writeln("HELLO");
}

func();
```

Or this:

```
(function() {
    document.writeln("HELLO");
})();
```

Comment: Your answers are as good as your profile pic

Comment: +1 AMAZING! DUDE YOU'RE THE JS MASTER! `:)`

Comment: Why should I use parenthesis in the second example? See update in my question.

Comment: @VladimirBezugliy Because in your update `v` gets value of `"HELLO"`. `()` means immediate calling of the defined function.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
(function() {
  document.writeln('HELLO');
})();
```

Comment: Why should I use parenthesis in the second example? See update in my question.