# Jquery global ajax event handler w/ json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make global ajax handler of general purpose responses. (Eg. refresh page)

Is there any handler or hack so i'd get already parsed json, so i woudn't have to parse it twice?

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr) {
    // Validate and parse xhr.responseText TWICE!
});
```

Okay, found a bit "hacky" solution, maybe useful to others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to override jquery ajax json parser:

```
function parseJsonResponse(d) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(d); // Same as default

    // Do anything with json object :)

    return json;
}
// Override original parser, defaults to jQuery.parseJSON.
jQuery.ajaxSettings.converters['text json'] = parseJsonResponse;
```

And if you dont want `parseJsonResponse` to be a *global function* then you can put this code in [self-executing anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m)