# Passing objects in JS Function in recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I'm working on this currently:

- I have a div "out" and a button "in".
- Click the button, Create div "extra" and button "extra_b"
- At the same time, "out"and "in" hide.
- click "extra_b", "out"and "in" appears, and **DELETE** "extra" and button "extra_b"

Here is the sample:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/BGJ5T/5/)

It can't work, and after I checked console, It probably tells me:

```
inner.onclick=function(){ add(outer[i]) };
```

unable to pass the object of current out element to the function correctly:

```
function add(objectIn){
}
```

Could you please tell me how to pass the elements to a function in a recursion? And how to modify my current code to make it run correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kuraiinazuma of course yes

Comment: @Darklizard nwm in blind :)

Comment: @Quentin perhaps no. My recursion is used to apply functions to all the main elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [common problem is JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m).
When you are binding the onclick event, you are not using the current value of `i` but rather when the click happens, the last value of `i` is used.

So you have to do:

`inner.onclick= (function(i){ return function(){ add(outer[i]) })(i);`

Comment: Many thanks!! And little mistakes on bracket in your code: inner.onclick=  function(i){ return function(){ add(outer[i]) } }(i);

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a new closure like Darhazer suggested, or you if you don't mind using jQuery you can use jQuery.proxy():

```
inner.onclick = $.proxy(add, window, outer[i]);
```