# how does jquery make the $ do what it does?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to use the $ symbol in jquery and not have to use jQuery.functionname, we use this

```
(function($) {

})(jQuery);
```

(In drupal, you actually have to specify this implicitly).

I don't understand this javascript syntax, why is there an initial parentheses? How is the (jQuery) at the end used?

Comment: It's an *immediately invoked anonymous function expression.* Has been discussed untold times before. `$` is simply a variable name.

Comment: the first function variable is $ and then you're calling it passing jQuery....and what he said ^

Comment: I'm sure I was discussed elsewhere, but I didn't know how to look it up. I looked up immediate invoked javascript and now I found the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Understand closure [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @deceze It's not necessarily easy to find that information if you don't know what the construct is called (and why would you if you don't know what it is), though.

Comment: Self executing ananymous function which passes `jQuery` as parameter

Comment: @Anthony Admittedly, yes, absolutely. But some random googling and poking around should have let to that conclusion sooner or later IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an anonymous function with an argument that's automatically invoked.

For example, if we were to expand it out a bit you'd end up with something like this:

```
var anon = function($) {
    ...
};

anon(jQuery);
```

The `$` is a valid identifer in JavaScript and we pass in the existing `jQuery` object into the function for use through `$`, as it could be replaced later.

Answer (score 0):

All that's doing is declaring an anonymous function and executing it immediately, passing in one argument (`jQuery`) into the function. That argument is given the name `$` which can be used throughout the scope of the function.

The brackets around the function aren't strictly necessary in all contexts; see the comment under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/440772/65387) for details. The gist is that they're needed here to make the function behave like an expression instead of a statement (function declaration).