# Can someone explain how this function works? function{} (function

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me how this works / what it does (more specifically the ( before the function) as I don't understand why the function after inArray has a ( around it?

```
function geoip(g){window.top.location.href=inArray(g.country_code,filter)?targetVisitorsUrl:allVisitorsUrl}
    function inArray(r,n){for(var t=n.length,e=0;t>e;e++)if(n[e]==r)return!0;return!1}
    (function(g,e,o,i,p){i=g.createElement(e),p=g.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];i.async=0;i.src=o;p.parentNode.insertBefore(i,p)})(document,'script','https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=test&callback=geoip');
```

Thank you

Comment: Googling for “javascript function in parentheses” or similar could have easily lead you to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/q/440739/10283047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking what [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is.

IIFE stands for Immediately Invoked Function Expression. The disambiguation is self-descriptive. It's just a function that is invoked immediately:

```
(function () { alert( ' immediate alert! ' ) })()
```