# how does javaScript function with parentheses around it works

Tags: javascript

I came across this function while learning on freecodecamp and I am quite lost on how it works. I am relatively new to JavaScript and I would appreciate if someone could explain better on how function with parentheses around it works. I would be glad if a link with well detailed explanation is also provided.

```
arr1 = ["monday", "tuesday", "wenesday","thursday", "friday"];
(function() {
  arr2 = [...arr1]; // change this line
  arr1[0] = 'potato'
})();
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Why-are-parenthesis-used-to-wrap-a-JavaScript-function-call

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-an-object-function-class-declaration-mean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript

Comment: It's called an IIFE. Please visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE for detailed information.