# Tampermonkey's new script template syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

If I create a new script in Tampermonkey it inserts the following template code:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
})();
```

I know that `function() {...}` is an anonymous function but what ist `(...)()` and what is it good for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do parentheses surrounding an object/function/class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-an-object-function-class-declaration-mean)

Comment: @icecub Your previous – now deleted – comment did it already. With the proper keywords _self-invoking anonymous function_ [it's easy to find](https://tensor-programming.com/anonymous-functions-in-javascript/#crayon-5dfea211336af567949727).

Comment: I know, but as not to leave the question open / unanswered, I marked it as a duplicate. Just following SO's guidelines :)